# De array a pdf con laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

Tengo un array de datos, estos vienen de una consulta a una base de datos. Estoy intentando pasar los datos de ese array para que me aparezcan en un pdf en formato tabla. No puedo acceder a los datos ni a traves de map ni nada. ¿Como podría hacerlo?

El contenido del array es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo formo con php desde el backend de esta manera:

```
     $resultsArray = [];
    
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $resultsArray[] = [
                'analog_id_d' => $row['analog_id_d'],
                'hist_codigo_d' => $row['hist_codigo_d'],
                'hist_fecha_d' => $row['hist_fecha_d']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'hist_valor_d' => $row['hist_valor_d']
            ];
        }

   if (!empty($resultsArray)) {
            return response()->json(['results' => $resultsArray]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'No se encontraron resultados']);
}
```

Y desde el lado cliente con javascript recojo el array así:

```
 // Realizar la solicitud AJAX al backend (Laravel) para obtener los datos y generar el PDF
                        fetch('/generar-pdf', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify(filtro)
                        })
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(resultados => {
                             // Verifica que los resultados se estén cargando correctamente
                                console.log("RESULTADOS", resultados);
                               
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            // Manejar errores
                        });
```

Comment: La variable `resultados` que obtienes como respuesta, es un objeto que tiene una clave llamada `results`, la cual sí es un Array. Deberías poder acceder así: `resultados.results.map( ... )` o puedes usar `destrucutre syntax` así: `const { results } = resultados;` para luego trabajar con el array de `results` directamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `resultados` que obtienes como respuesta, es un objeto que tiene una clave llamada `results`, la cual sí es un Array. Deberías poder acceder así:

```js
.then(resultados => {
  if(resultados.results) {
    resultados.results.map( ... );
  }
})
```

O puedes usar [sintaxis de desestructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) así:

```js
.then(resultados => {
  const { results } = resultados;
  if(results) {
    results.map( ... );
  }
})
```

Esto se ve claramente de la forma en que creas el objeto para ser devuelto por PHP:

```php
return response()->json(['results' => $resultsArray]);
```

Si deseas devolver directament el Array y no un objeto, entonces hazlo de la siguiente manera:

```php
return response()->json($resultsArray);
```

**Nota**

Recuerda siempre verificar que `results` exista antes de intentar usar `map` sobre dicha variable.

**Nota 2**

Tal vez lo que te confunde es creer que estás pasando un Array al método `json()` del objeto `response` en PHP. Lo cierto es que sí estás pasando un Array, pero es un [Array Asociativo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (nombre propio en el lenguaje PHP), que al ser convertido a JSON, su notación es de [Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), ya que en Javascript, un Objeto es lo mismo que un [Array Asociativo de PHP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/associative-arrays-in-php/).